# How to find closest matching adjacent row in a table

Tags: jquery

Using Jquery, how can I find the closest adjacent row matching a pattern.

I have a table of rows, where one row represents the header of the following rows until the next header. I have a click handler from an element within one of the rows. Starting from the element clicked, how can I find the nearest header row?

I tried `.closest(".header")` but there's no results because it's not a parent. I also can't look for `.parent().closest(".header")` as there are many rows matching that description.

```
...
<tr class="header"></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr> // <-- starting here, find tr above with class "header"
<tr></tr>
<tr class="header"></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
...
```

I am developing an extension and can not change the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.prev`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) will search among preceeding siblings, so you can use that and select the last one in the collection:

```
const prevHeader = $(theTr).prev('.header').last();
```

Comment: Turns out there was many matching header rows but only the header with a H3 child is the main header. (I didn't write this html). After I wrote the post I discovered `prevAll`. My solution was `thisRow.prevAll(".header").find("h3").last()`. But I'll mark yours as the correct solution.